# Concat multiple regex

Tags: java, regex

I try to create a regex which matchs with IPv4.

I have this code

```
//numbers from 10 to 99
String r10to99 = "[1-9][0-9]";

//numbers from 100 to 199
String r100to199 = "1[0-9][0-9]"; 

//numbers from 200 to 255
String r200to255 = "2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]"; 

//combine all - numbers from 0 to 255   
String r0to255 = "[0-9]|" + r10to99 + "|" + r100to199 + "|" + r200to255; 

String regexIP = r0to255 + "[.]" + r0to255 + "[.]" + r0to255 + "[.]" + r0to255; 

System.out.println("15.15.15.15".matches(regexIP)); //->false - should be true
System.out.println("15".matches(regexIP)); //->true - should be false
```

My problem is at `regexIP`. It match only with numbers from 0 to 255. Like `r0to255`.

How to concat multiple `r0to255` with `.(dot)` between them?

`r0to255.r0to255.r0to255.r0to255`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group these patterns, see the fixed code:

```
String r10to99 = "[1-9][0-9]"; //numbers from 10 to 99
String r100to199 = "1[0-9][0-9]"; //numbers from 100 to 199
String r200to255 = "2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]"; //numbers from 200 to 255

//combine all - numbers from 0 to 255   
String r0to255 = "(?:[0-9]|" + r10to99 + "|" + r100to199 + "|" + r200to255 + ")"; 

String regexIP = r0to255 + "(?:[.]" + r0to255 + "){3}"; 

System.out.println("15.15.15.15".matches(regexIP)); // true
System.out.println("15".matches(regexIP)); // false
```

See [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/UvNCMB)

Here, `"(?:[0-9]|" + r10to99 + "|" + r100to199 + "|" + r200to255 + ")"` groups the `r10to99`, `r100to199`  and `r200to255` so as inside a larger pattern (using a [*non-capturing group*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do)), the `|` would not ruin the whole pattern.

The `r0to255 + "(?:[.]" + r0to255 + "){3}"` pattern is actually a `r0to255` pattern that is followed with three sequences of `.` and `r0to255` pattern.

Comment: Using `?:` at `r0to255` mean to resolve all, without changing my regexIP. It is necesary to use `?:` at `regexIP`?

Comment: @raul1ro You are right, but `ababab` pattern is too verbose, the `(?:ab){3}` notation is easier and more maintainable. Well, it is up to you.

Answer (score -1):

For the sake of completeness, of course [Apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html) already has a solution for this.

Comment: I know that, but why is wrong to try to implement my own method? By trying to find a regex for that I learned new things.